# undefined when trying to access an element in json object

Tags: javascript, json

How come the first `alert` shows `Dublin` but the second is `undefined`?

http://jsfiddle.net/pzdx6L5a/1/

```
function getRenderParamValue(query){
    customContext = JSON.parse("{\"test\":true,\"geo\":\"\",\"city\":\"Dublin\",\"categoryId\":\"\",\"categoryName\":\"\",\"productId\":\"\"}");
    alert(customContext.city);
    return customContext.query;
}

alert('city: ' + getRenderParamValue('city'));
```

Comment: It should be `return customContext[query];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking for a property 'query', which doesn't exist.
Use `[]` instead of `.`:

```
return customContext[query];
```